# Rails self referrential associations, how to determine mutual intersection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, self-reference

I want to have friends/followers mechanzm, so I've created following DB structure:

```
user_id
friend_id
```

I want to know what's the easiest and simplest way to determine (Rails-way) that following users are mutual friends?

```
user_id        friend_id
1              2
2              1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
test_pair = [1,2]
Friendship.where(user_id: test_pair, friend_id: test_pair).count == 2
```